# Rails6で、実行環境時にFont Awesomeの絵文字が四角に表示される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarn

### 環境

- Ruby 2.6.3
- Ruby on Rails 6.0.0
- Yarn 1.22.4
- Webpacker 5.1.1
- @fortawesome/fontawesome-free 5.13.0

### 問題

記事（https://techracho.bpsinc.jp/hachi8833/2020_01_17/85943）の通りにRailsにYarnでFontawesomeパッケージを導入し、以下のように設定しました。

**application.scss**

```
$fa-font-path: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

**application.js**

```
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free")
```

開発環境（localhost:3000）では、Chrome開発コンソールとターミナル上にエラーは出ず、絵文字も表示されました。しかし、実行環境では、絵文字が □ のように表示され、以下の通りのエラーが出ました。

**Chrome コンソール**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) fa-solid-900.woff2:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) fa-solid-900.woff:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) fa-solid-900.tff:1
```

**ターミナル**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff"):
...
```

なぜ開発環境では絵文字が表示され、実行環境では表示されないのか分かりません。

初学者ですので、下らない質問ではあると存じますが、どうかお願い致します。

Comment: 開発環境と実行環境の違いは何か？についても記載があると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

config/environments/production.rb で `config.assets.compile = true` とすることで解決しました。

Comment: 小規模な利用であれば、特に問題はないかとは思いますが、基本的には`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile`の方が推奨のようです。理由は、メモリーの消費とパフォーマンスの低下にあるようです。詳しくは、https://railsguides.jp/asset_pipeline.html#%E3%82%A2%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B の`config.assets.precompile = true`にした場合のところを見てみてください。